# How can take parent iframe as IElement using DotNetBrowser?

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

I need write function for take real top and left element in window.
In DotNetBrowser we can take coordinates:

```
int Y = el.BoundingClientRect.Origin.Y;
int X = el.BoundingClientRect.Origin.X;
```

but its give no real coordinates if element into iframe.

I write some metod for taking real coordinates:

```
public int realY(IElement el)
        {
            IFrame f = el.Frame;
            if (f.IsMain)
            {
                return el.BoundingClientRect.Origin.Y;
            }
            else
            { 
                IElement fel = GetElementByAtrTag("iframe", "name", f.Name);
                return el.BoundingClientRect.Origin.Y + fel.BoundingClientRect.Origin.Y;
            }
        }
```

but its not universal, becouse iframe not alredy have name (what I use in this method) or can be many parent iframe.

I try go other way, and for me need can take element parent iframe as IElement without id or name, having only Child IElement, example:

```
public IElement FindIframe(IElement el)
        {
            if (el.Parent.NodeName != "IFRAME")
            {
                
                return FindIframe((IElement)el.Parent);
            }
            else return (IElement)el.Parent;
        }
```

this metod fail when up to parent iframe element, and his have NodeName - #document

I can take first parent iframe so:

```
IFrame parentElFrame = el.Frame;
```

but IFrame have not BoundingClientRect.

DotNetBrowser have IFrameElement and this element have BoundingClientRect, but I cant convert IFrame to IFrameElement

Where I can go?

Answer (score 2):

and I make so method for return parent iframe for inside element:

```
public IElement FindIframe(IElement el)
        {
            string docframe = el.Frame.Document.DocumentElement.OuterHtml;
            IEnumerable<IElement> elements = ActiveTab.browser.MainFrame.Document.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("iframe");
            foreach(IElement e in elements)
            {
                IFrameElement ef = (IFrameElement)e;
                
                if (ef.ContentDocument.DocumentElement.OuterHtml == docframe)
                {
                    return e;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

after I can make method for taking real coordinates for elements inside iframe:

```
public Point realPlace(IElement el)
        {
            Point p = new Point(0, 0);
            p.X = el.BoundingClientRect.Origin.X;
            p.Y = el.BoundingClientRect.Origin.Y;
            if (!el.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                Point pin = realPlace((IElement)FindIframe(el));
                p.X += pin.X;
                p.Y += pin.Y;
                
            }
            return p;
        }
```